# How to fix spacing issues with headers and footers?

Tags: arrays, swift, header, footer, spacing

I have a header and a footer make in code. The problem I am having is that the footer of the current section impedes on the last cell in said section. Second, how do I add blank lines of space between the current sections footer and the next sections header?

Header code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return myTitles[section]
    }
```

Footer code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return("Total Emojis: \(emojis[section].count)")
    }
```

Comment: It failed to compile with the error "Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'String?' "    And I get the error "Unterminated string literal"

Comment: You're missing a `"` at the end of your string.

Comment: That fixed it. The weird thing now is that the output impedes on the last cell of the sections and there is no space between the footer of the current section and the header of the following section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a view for header and footer instead of `titleForHeaderInSection` and `titleForFooterInSection` .

For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            
                let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 18))
                let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: view.centerX - 50, y: view.centerY, width: 100, height: 40))
                label.text = myTitles[section]
                label.textAlignment = .center
                view.addSubview(label)
                
                return view       
    }
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        
            return 60 
    }
```

And for footer you can use the same concept.